# Finding an invertible submatrix

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

Given an m by n full rank matrix with n>m, what is an efficient algorithm for choosing m rows from the matrix to form an invertible (full rank) m by m submatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Let `M` be the matrix, `M(j)` the `j`-th column and `M(i,j)` the entry at row `i` and column `j`.

for `j` from `1` to `m`:

1. Choose the first row that has a non-zero entry `M(i,j)` in column `j`. This row is named `i`.
2. Use `M(i,j)` to set every other entry of this row to zero by computing

   ```
    M(k) = M(k) - M(i,k)/M(i,j) * M(j) for 1 <= k <= n and k != j
   ```
3. update the matrix with the columns computed in step 2.

Since the matrix is of rank `m`, you will find `m` rows that have a non-zero entry.
This algorithm runs in `O(n*m^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to choose m columns, not m rows.

Row-reduce the transpose and pick the pivot rows of the transpose.  They correspond to one valid choice of columns.